# Converting .adf files into NetCDF

Tags: r, raster, arcgis, netcdf, arcmap

I have a set of .adf files which contain spatially distributed data. The files look like this:

```
dblbnd.adf
hdr.adf
metadata.xml
prj.adf
sta.adf
w001001.adf
w001001x.adf
```

I can read in the large file (w001001.adf) into R as a raster. This is the raster characteristics:

```
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1692, 3611, 6109812  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 6, 6  (x, y)
extent     : -10833.68, 10832.32, -4713.677, 5438.323  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : C:/Users/ahsa361/Documents/CEDS_Data/gridding-preprocessing/input/Corbett/w001001.adf 
names      : w001001 
values     : 0, 5637.337  (min, max)
```

I would like to convert this to NetCDF with dimensions of 180 deg lat. x 360 deg lon. at 0.5 deg resolution. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I don't understand why you say " it doesn't look like it has regular longitude and latitude values". What sort of "regular" do you expect?

Comment: I mean to say that I would like it to be in 180 deg lat x 360 deg long at 0.5 deg resolution. The dimensions of the raster I posted does not match this. (I've edited the post)

Answer (score 1):

You have an extent that does not match your coordinate reference system

```
#extent     : -10833.68, 10832.32, -4713.677, 5438.323  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

Without more information it not really possible to help you much. Most likely the crs is wrong and you need to replace it with the correct one. Did you set it to the wrong value? (that is the most common cause of this problem). If you know what it should be, you can set it like this

```
 crs(x) <- "correct crs definition"
```

It is also possible that the extent is wrong, and you could also set that to the right value. But based on the what you say, you do not know, so you need to figure these things out before we can help with *how* to fix your problem.

To get a global extent, and a resolution close to 0.1 degrees, you can do

```
 extent(x) <- c(-180,180,-90,90)
```

Given the number of rows and columns you have, that would get you:

```
library(raster)
raster(nrow=1692, ncol=3611)
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 1692, 3611, 6109812  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 0.09969538, 0.106383  (x, y)
#extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

Comment: Thank you @Robert Hijmans for the input. I did not modify any of the files, so it's strange that they have inconsistent attributes. I believe they were originally rendered from 0.1° x 0.1° grid cells resolved globally and contained a single variable. Does this help in any way?

Comment: see expanded answer